# How to get scroll value for keyboard ondrag in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am using onDrag functionality to hide keyboard in iOS chat view controller. The problem is I can't get the scroll value when dragging keyboard to hide (I need exactly like whats app messenger keyboard dismiss by using swiping keyboard).

So, I used

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keypadWillChange(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

Selector,

```
 @objc func keypadWillChange(_ notification: Notification) {
 
        print("Dragging...")
 }
```

When I drag the function `keypadWillChange` is not called. Any other alternatives to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UITableView`, in `UIStoryboard` do the following.

1. Go to `Attribute Inspector`.
2. In `UIScrollView` section, there is a keyboard settings item.
3. Dismiss interactively  option in drop down menu behaves exactly as `WhatsApp` keyboard.

Comment: Yes, I am already using it. The problem is when dismissing keyboard by Swipe, the other views are in top.

Comment: Hi Mount Ain, As I understand, keyboard should be on top of tableView. I did not understand the point that "other views are in top". Will it be possible to show it pictorially.